# Understanding how Haskell functions are applied

Tags: haskell

I am doing Nicta course exercises and there I ran into an example that I don't understand.
I have two functions and their types are as follows:

```
filtering :: Applicative f => (a -> f Bool) -> List a -> f (List a)

(>) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Then I apply `filtering` to `(>)` and check the type is GHCi. the resulting type is :

```
filtering (>) :: Ord a => List a -> a -> List a
```

I don't understand how this result came about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand what the expression `filtering (>)` means, you should know which instance of Applicative is used here.

Actually, [the instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-641) `Applicative ((->) a)` is used here, which specializes the function filtering to the following type (notice that we use `(b ->)` instead of `((->) a)` below, which is the same)

```
filtering :: (a -> (b -> Bool)) -> List a -> (b -> (List a))
```

And when applied `(>)`, to unify `(a -> (b -> Bool))` and `(a -> (a -> Bool))`, we know that b must equal to a, so `filtering` is specialized to

```
filtering :: (a -> (a -> Bool)) -> List a -> (a -> (List a))
```

And so we get the type of `filtering (>)` directly

```
filtering (>) :: (Ord a) => List a -> (a -> (List a))
```

which is just same as what GHCi is given.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler tries unify two types: `a -> (a -> Bool)` with `b -> f Bool`. It sees that lhs and rhs are functions. So, it tries unify `a = b` and `a -> Bool = f Bool`. The `a = b` is unified. The `a -> Bool` equivalent with `(->) a Bool`. So, from `(->) a Bool = f Bool` it gets that `f = (->) a`. And if we apply the substitute `f = (->) a` to type expression `List a -> f (List a)` we'll get: `List a -> (->) a (List a)` which equivalent with `List a -> a -> List a`